# Maven project with java and groovy source folders, how to denote in POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy, m2e

I found this in one of my poms to change the test directory for Groovy.

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```

The problem is that there is both Java and Groovy classes in `src/main/` (`src/main/java` and `src/main/groovy` respectively). Otherwise I'd do the same for `src/test/groovy`.

What is the proper way to include `src/main/groovy` while also including `src/main/java` so that when I import this with m2e I don't need to manually add `src/main/groovy` as a source folder?

I ask because even though I have the dependency in the pom and the other project in Eclipse's build path, Eclipse can't find a class from this project unless I manually add the jar as an external dependency.

Comment: Are you using the `groovy-eclipse-plugin`? If so, you can just toss Groovy and Java files in the same directories and don't need to distinguish.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I am, but I don't want to restructure this (and every other) project. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You should use the groovy-eclipse-plugin, it is the recommended way to do it. The docs clearly explain how to handle this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the advice given by the official [Groovy documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/tools-groovyc.html#_maven_integration).

**EDIT**

*The official recommendation changed some time in 2015: they now recommend using the Ant Run plugin*

Add the following to your pom (in the plugins section) and remove that `testSourceDirectory` from your pom.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/src/test/groovy"/>
                    <taskdef name="groovyc"
                             classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
                        <classpath refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
                    </taskdef>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
                    <groovyc destdir="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"
                             srcdir="${basedir}/src/test/groovy/" listfiles="true">
                        <classpath refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
                    </groovyc>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Add a `compile` execution as well for the `src/main/groovy` dir and for any other location your Groovy files might be located.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Choose [one of their 4 options](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin) to solve this, and remove this `testSourceDirectory` from your pom.

In your case, I would use the last, most verbose option, as it keeps the standard Maven lifecycle intact and makes it really explicit what's going on...

So, after removing your previous configuration, add this to the pom:

```
<build>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-source</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>src/main/groovy</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>add-test-source</id>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>src/test/groovy</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Notice that even though you may even mix groovy and java files in either `src/main/java` AND `src/main/groovy` (as well as the test folders), things will get really confusing and I would strongly advise against that having worked with Java/Groovy mixed code for a while.

Comment: The key is to add test sources, not to replace them.  This is the right answer.  If you have groovy test resources, consider adding them (maven buildhelper addResources) as src/test/groovyResources

Comment: @Edwin yeah, I agree. I didn't make this pom, that's why I worsed the question as "found" instead of "wrote".

Comment: @CaptainMan you may have forgotten to accept the answer :)

Comment: Broken link to groovy doco

Comment: @wytten looks like the advice has changed... they recommend using the Ant plugin (which I agree is a better choice). So the link is gone. To follow the advice given in this answer, the link is now here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin

Comment: Edited the answer with the new advice and fixed the links. Thanks for pointing out!